# Interfacing Arduino UNO with TFT LCD and WiFi Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, lcd

I'm trying to interface my Arduino UNO with both a 1) TFT LCD screen and 2) WiFi Breakout board/shield.
The WiFi breakout board uses many of the same Digital pins as the LCD screen so is it possible for the arduino to interface with both devices simultaneously?

I also noticed that the shield goes over the arduino, but covers the header pins. Does this mean that I can't use these pins?

I've never worked with shields or breakout boards and would like some advice before I purchase either component. 
If neither of these solutions will work, please provide me with alternate methods.

Your time/feedback is greatly appreciated :)

-Vip

Comment: This isn't a very well matched selection of parts - even if you get the wiring to work (there are probably ways) both an LCD display and wifi tend to need a fair amount of RAM to use effectively, and your Uno has a mere 2048 bytes which will require very careful budgeting.  You would do much better with a processor having both more memory as well as more pins.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Chris on this. The uno is limited where it comes to pins and and ram, you should probably look at a mega, or similar.

As far as running both at once, i don't think it would be possible with the uno, with the ram limitations, as well as pin limitations, you'll be hard pressed to get them going at the same time, within the same sketch.

While technically it is possible to use alternative pins, i doubt there will be enough unused pins to shift an entire shield over to on the Uno

If you're looking for a cheaper rout, you may look at adding a secondary Uno to run the wifi, and send any data you need displayed to the uno running the tft via serial coms.

Comment: Thank you both for the great feedback. @ArcAIN6 Is there a link to a tutorial where I can interface two Uno's like you mentioned?

Thanks again.